# Outdated gpg version on Big Sur

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, homebrew, big-sur, gpg

It seems that the the current `gpg` installed on Big Sur is a bit outdated compared with the one bottled from `homebrew`.

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.0.30
libgcrypt 1.7.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA, RSA, ELG, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Similar if I try with `gpg2`

```
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.0.30
libgcrypt 1.7.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA, RSA, ELG, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

If I'm not mistaken with the current version seems to be no support for elliptic curve algos, e.g. `ed25519`.

Brew says that the latest version of `gpg` is `2.3.4`

```
brew info gpg
gnupg: stable 2.3.4 (bottled)
GNU Pretty Good Privacy (PGP) package
https://gnupg.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/gnupg.rb
License: GPL-3.0-or-later
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gettext ✔, gnutls ✔, libassuan ✔, libgcrypt ✔, libgpg-error ✔, libksba ✔, libusb ✘, npth ✔, pinentry ✘
```

The locations of the installed gpg versions are the following:

```
which gpg
/usr/local/bin/gpg

which gpg2
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg2
```

My question is if I uninstall `gpg` and `gpg2` and then install using `brew` will I have any issues?

Or put it another way, what is the appropriate method of updating the current `gpg` version `2.0.30` to `2.3.4`.

Comment: If the executables are in /usr/local or below then they are NOT supplied by Apple. Thus for upgrade you need to look at the documentation of the process that you used to install them

Comment: Apple does not ship a GPL3-licensed copy of GnuPG.  Or any copy of GnuPG.

Comment: Also, as of writing the most recent version of https://gpgtools.org/macgpg2/ uses gnupg 2.2.34

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it seems that gpgtools had an issue and whenever was checking about updates was coming back with the message you're on the latest version, this resulted in gpgtools being stuck in a version using gpg 2.0.3

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by uninstlling completely the [gpgtools.org](https://gpgtools.org/macgpg2/) using their uninstall .dmg image from their website and installed a clean copy `gpg` using `homebrew`.